# Can I just include rosjava.jar and develop in eclipse?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying to do this all day. I've had my android development environment set up and running in Windows and I have limited experience in ubuntu. I've spent the better part of the last 18 hours trying to get a simple example working in Android. The only way I could get a .jar to show up was by downloading through debian. However it does not have all the libraries I need such as org.ros.messages.std_msgs. I've tried just recreating the two classes from the Google+WG Demo talk at Google IO, but have not been able to without the std_msgs.

Any tips or hints are appreciated.

*Edit* - I am trying to work on android

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11830/can-i-just-include-rosjava.jar-and-develop-in-eclipse?/) by [mouser58907](https://answers.ros.org/users/1327/mouser58907/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2011-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should try install rosjava from source. Then, you can try to get one of the examples running (e.g. rosjava_tutorial_pubsub, android_tutorial_pubsub). After running rosmake in one of these packages, you should be able to import it as an Eclipse project (the project files are generated via rosmake). For Android, you'll also need to rosmake and import at least the android_gingerbread library project.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2011-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1